# What is the difference between COM Classes and CoClasses

Tags: windows, oop, com

The [Wikipedia COM article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Classes) is vague when it comes to this issue.

Can anybody give an explanation that would be suitable for a COM beginner, or article link(s) providing the same.

Comment: Same thing.  I suspect they picked "coclass" to keep it separate from classes in programming languages.  Very different, a coclass exposes no implementation.  Only interfaces, discovered at runtime with QI.

Comment: `Essential COM` by Don Box is the standard introductory reference.

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to think about it the following way:

A COM class to me is an instance of a class that implements a certain interface. I don't need to know how the implementation is done, as long as it works as expected. Also, a COM class is not language dependent - it's a description of methods.

A Co-Class is an actual implementation that gets instantiated when requesting a COM class.

For example: A COM class could define method to encrypt or decrypt data. There could be two Co-Classes, each for a special encryption algorithm.

Comment: It's still unclear what is a class. Is it assumed to support a specific set of interfaces?

Comment: I'm confused by how a class can be an instance and also just a description of methods. The latter sounds like an interface.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understand, too. A COM class is basically an interface, the Co-Class is the implementation.

Comment: But then what is a COM interface for? e.g. IUnknown

Answer (score 1):

[`coclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is nothing but a type library declaration of a class. There are no assumptions on interfaces implemented by a class (other than perhaps `IUnknown`, or the class makes no sense), however if a declaration references certain interfaces within the type library, it is expected that real instance would implement those.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain how this differs from a class.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question, coclass stands for "component object class"; it is the same thing as "COM class". Your Wikipedia link answers this exactly:

> A COM class (coclass) is...